# RobotFramework with docker cause an InvalidSessionIdException error

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, robotframework

I'm trying to use robotframework to implement CI workflow.
The process is running in docker with the following command line.

CODE :

```
docker run --network="my-network" 
 -v /.../frontend/e2e/reports:/opt/robotframework/reports:Z 
 -v /.../frontend/e2e:/opt/robotframework/tests:Z 
 -e BROWSER=chrome ppodgorsek/robot-framework:5.0.0
```

During the test, the web driver is encountering some errors.

LOGS :

```
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Message: invalid session id
...
| FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Stacktrace:
...
1) Evaluating expression '$webdriver.get_log('browser')' failed: InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
...
```

Then, all the test suite is failing.
no one has any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the following configuration, everything is back to normal.

```
Open Chrome Browser to Page
[Arguments]    ${URL}
${chrome_options}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    test-type
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
# Maximize Browser Window  # doesn't work under XVFB
Set Window Size    1920    1080
Go To    ${URL}
```